# Minikube ingress controller not forwarding request to deployed service properly

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-service

I have following setup in minikube cluster

1. SpringBoot app deployed in minikube cluster

> name : opaapp and containerPort: 9999

2. Service use to expose service app as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: opaapp
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: opaapp
spec:
  selector:
    app: opaapp
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 9999
      targetPort: 9999
  type: NodePort
```

3. Created an ingreass controller and ingress resource as below

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 # for versions before 1.14 use extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: opaapp-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: opaapp.info
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: opaapp
          servicePort: 9999
```

I have setup host file as below

```
172.17.0.2    opaapp.info
```

Now, if I access service as below

http://opaapp.info:32746/api/ping  :  I am getting the response back

But if I try to access as

http://opaapp.info/api/ping : Getting 404 error

Not able to find the error on configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nginx ingress controller has been exposed via NodePort `32746` which means nginx is not listening on port 80/443 in the host's(172.17.0.2) network, rather nginx is listening on port 80/443 on Kubernetes pod network which is different than host network. Hence accessing it via  `http://opaapp.info/api/ping` is not working. To make it work the way you are expecting the nginx ingress controller need to be deployed with `hostNetwork: true` option so that it can listen on 80/443 port directly in the host(172.17.0.2) network which can be done as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56915354/how-to-install-nginx-ingress-with-hostnetwork-on-bare-metal).

Comment: Thanks for your input .. I got the point .. but my problem is .. in minikube I haven't installed ingress controller externally. I did enable ingress ..and set ingress resource through yml file . How can I set hostNetwork true in that case .. again thanks

Comment: I am not sure if this will work but you can try by editing the deployment of nginx ingress controller to add hostNetwork: true

Comment: I have updated the deployment with hostNetwork: true , and deploy it again. I can see it appears in pod level also. still getting the same error . Do i need to deploy the ingress resource and service again .. cause still http://opaapp.info/api/ping is not working

Comment: you updated the nginx ingress controller deployment not the opaapp deployment right?

Comment: Yes .. i found it from kube-system namespace and update it there ..                                           restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress
      serviceAccount: nginx-ingress
      hostNetwork: true
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler

Comment: check if a process is listening in the host on port 80/443

Comment: Yes. nginx on ubuntu was running on 80 .. I did kill that one also .. but no luck ..same error

Comment: Thanks Arghya .. Thanks a lot... nice to meet you also ..  it is working now .. I need to change annotation as  and deployed it again                                                                                                                      annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"